# Minimise computational cost for given level of MSE

Tags: computational-complexity, maxima-minima, monte-carlo, mean-square-error

[image: Example]

I am trying to understand how to minimise cost of a Monte Carlo implementation for a given value of MSE/RMSE.

Please see the notes attached...I do not follow the second line.

I would be grateful if someone could explain.

Thanks, and best wishes,
HP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is stated, we have $$MSE(h)=aC^{-1}h^{-\gamma}+bh^{2\alpha}$$to find the minimum, we need to find the roots of $${\partial MSE(h)\over \partial h}=0$$which leads to $$-\gamma C^{-1}h^{-\gamma-1}+2\alpha bh^{2\alpha-1}=0$$and by simplification $$\gamma C^{-1}h^{-\gamma}=2\alpha bh^{2\alpha}$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Very well explained. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. Wish you luck within the rest of your work!